# Get too many results

Tags: android

I'm trying to create Favorites class. I search for title I get from the user and adds the video to the Favorites class. But, I always get more than one result. ( I get the maximum results which is 10 ).
How can I get only 1 result for each title?

This is the on create:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.favorites_layout);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Favorites");
    initializeViews();

    extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    this.vidTitle = extras.getString("title");
    this.vidID = extras.getString("id");
    //Checking where to add the new Video
    for(int i=0;i<favorites.length;i++){
        if(favorites[i]==null){
            favorites[i] = vidTitle;
        }
        break; // Break so it won't add same video to all array
    }
    AppUtils.showToast("Loading Favorites");
    getVideo2();
}
```

This is the code which gets the 10 results:

```
    public void getVideo(){
    AppUtils.showToast("Loading Favorites");
    mServiceTask = new ServiceTask(SEARCH_VIDEO);
    mServiceTask.setmServerResponseListener(this);
    for (int i=0; i<favorites.length;i++) {
        if(favorites[i]!=null){
            mServiceTask.execute(new Object[]{favorites[i]}); <--- Problem here
            break;
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

ServiceTask:

```
public class ServiceTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Object[]> implements ServiceTaskInterface{
private static final String TAG = ServiceTask.class.getSimpleName();
private ServerResponseListener mServerResponseListener = null;
private int mRequestCode = 0;

public void setmServerResponseListener(ServerResponseListener mServerResponseListener){
    this.mServerResponseListener = mServerResponseListener;
}

public ServiceTask(int iReqCode){
    mRequestCode = iReqCode;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    mServerResponseListener.prepareRequest(mRequestCode);
}

@Override
protected Object[] doInBackground(Object... params) {
    if(params == null)
        throw  new NullPointerException("Parameters to the async task can never be null");
    mServerResponseListener.goBackground();
    Object[] resultDetails = new Object[2];
    resultDetails[0] = mRequestCode;

    switch (mRequestCode){
        case AppConstants.SEARCH_VIDEO:
            try {
                resultDetails[1] = loadVideos((String) params[0]);
                break;
            }catch (Exception e){
                AppUtils.showToast("BLABLABLA");}

    }
    return  resultDetails;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object[] result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    mServerResponseListener.completedRequest(result);
}
//Loading the videos, with help of Google's code.
private List<SearchResult> loadVideos(String queryTerm){
    try{
        YouTube youTube = new YouTube.Builder(transport,jsonFactory,new HttpRequestInitializer() {
            @Override
            public void initialize(HttpRequest httpRequest) throws IOException {}
        }).setApplicationName(YoutubeApplication.appName()).build();
        YouTube.Search.List search = youTube.search().list("id,snippet");
        search.setKey(AppConstants.KEY);
        search.setQ(queryTerm);

        //Only including videos
        search.setType("video");

        search.setFields("items(id/kind,id/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/description,snippet/thumbnails/default/url,snippet/thumbnails/medium/url)");
        search.setMaxResults(AppConstants.NUMBER_OF_VIDEOS_RETURNED);

        //Call the API to print results
        SearchListResponse searchListResponse = search.execute();
        List<SearchResult> searchResultList = searchListResponse.getItems();
        if(searchResultList != null){
            return searchResultList;
        }
    }catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e){
        System.err.println("There was a service error: " + e.getDetails().getCode() + " : "
                + e.getDetails().getMessage());
    }catch (IOException e){
        System.err.println("There was an IO error: " + e.getCause() + " : " + e.getMessage());
    }catch (Throwable t){
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

How can I get only 1 result at time but still have place for 10 results ( like 10 different videos) ?

Answer (score 0):

At first, comment your `break;` lines or your loop is useless. Then collect your not null objects in list and place it in `execute` method with `toArray`.

```
    LinkedList<Object> list = new LinkedList<Object>();
    for (int i=0; i<favorites.length; i++) {
        if(favorites[i]!=null){
            //mServiceTask.execute(new Object[]{favorites[i]}); //<--- Problem here
            list.add(favorites[i]);
            //break;
        }
        else{
            //break;
        }
    }
    mServiceTask.execute(list.toArray());
```

**UPDATE**

And about `ServiceTask` class. In `doInBackground` you are using only `params[0]` - the first array element. So there should be:

```
for (int i=0; i<params.length; i++) {
    loadVideos((String) params[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the list stays null for some reason . I edited the post with more info .

Comment: What list? And is it null or just empty?

Comment: I fixed it, but still, I get 10 results for 1 video. I want to get 1 result at a time for different videos.. The Problem is the mServiceTask.execte returns 10 results. How can I limit it or at least, compare the results' id to the id I need?

Comment: Where is your `favorites` variable initialized? And show your `execute` method.

Comment: Thanks! and one more question, My array is static, when I change the keyword for search, the old thumbnails and titles are loaded but when I start the video it is the correct one. What can I do?

Comment: I guess you just don't refresh result list after changing keyword for search, so call `notifyDataSetChanged()` method by your adapter object after any change. I can't say more without code.

Comment: Thanks, It is now okay, but still , i get 10 results for 1 title, not 1 result for 1 title...

Comment: You are getting title with `this.vidTitle = extras.getString("title");` - it means you place in `Intent`'s extras only 1 title. You can put inside extras few titles inside, for example, `JSONArray`.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but it is 1 search, and if the user is searching for something else later, and wants to mark it as favorite too.

Comment: But `favorites` array is not a search keyword, isn't it?

Comment: Anyway, you are placing `vidTitle` as all `favorites` elements - it is not right.